# Is Selenium Grid 4 compatible with v3 clients?

Tags: selenium-grid, selenium4

Before I spent hours in setting up a Selenium v4 Grid, can someone confirm it is backward compatibility with existing clients?

I was not able to find anything in official documentation, nor in my searches.

We have an on-premises v3 implementation and all clients (mostly .NET and Java) are v3, so I am assessing the migration effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java project set up using Selenium 3.141.59 works with Selenium Grid 4.0.0.

All browsers work with the remote selenium grid except EdgeChromium. That requires you to migrate your project to Selenium 4.0.0

Below is my simple docker-compose setup for a small project using Selenium Grid 4.0.0 where we test using the latest chrome browser

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub-1:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0
    container_name: selenium-hub-1
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome-1:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    container_name: chrome-1
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub-1
    extra_hosts:
      - "dev-centos8:192.168.101.102"
      - "dev:192.168.101.102"
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub-1
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    volumes:
      - /downloads:/downloads
      - /apps/functional-test:/apps/functional-test
```

Comment: very interesting, thanks for the EdgeChromium tip

Answer (score 1):

after update to selenium4 all works fine with old selenium grid, but you need to refactor some part of your code

look what is [deprecated](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/deprecated-list.html) / [migration](https://docs.saucelabs.com/web-apps/automated-testing/selenium/selenium4/)

also you can see selenium source code for look what is deprecated

Comment: thanks @vvv but I want to know the opposite: what happens to _existing_ tests written for Selenium v3 when run on a Selenium v4 Grid.